# Equivalent usage in Swift for `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140500` or `#ifdef __IPHONE_14_5`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I write code on Xcode beta with new StoreKit API SKAdImpression, now I want to compile on lower version Xcode. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Just download Xcode version which you need from the Developer Apple resource https://developer.apple.com/download/more/  and start it.

Comment: #if(available ...)